solution-verification | Show that the number $10^n+100^n+1000^n-3$ is divisible by 9, whatever $n$ is a natural number.
the problem
Show that the number $10^n+100^n+1000^n-3$ is divisible by 9, whatever $n$ is a natural number.
my solution
if $n\geq 1$
First I wrote $10^n+ 10^{2n}+10^{3n}-3=10^n[1+10^n(1+10^n)]-3=100...0100...0100...0-3$
        how many times are the 0 repeating                         n-1    n-1     n     

then we get that the form of the numbers is actually    $100...0100...0999...97$
        how many times are the 0 repeating       n-1    n   n-1    

The number has the sum of the digits divisible by $9$ so the number is divisible by $9$
The case where $n=0$ can be easily verified
Im not sure if my idea is correct and if I got to the correct form. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

More simply: $10^n\equiv 1\pmod 9$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

your number plus $6$ has digit sum $9$

BY casting out nines or congruence arithmetic, the sum is $\equiv 1+1+1-3\equiv 0\pmod{9},,$ see the linked dupe. $\ \ $

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Please delete this duplicate question once all is clear.

No context here so this question doesn't meet the MSE Guidelines. Seems rather straightforward too I must say. -1

Your idea is correct, though It uses a "brutal force" approach. Here is an alternative proof:
Note that $10^n$, $100^n$ and $1000^n$ each leave a remainder of 1 when divided by 9. We denote this by $10^n \equiv 1(\bmod 9)$. For more details about this notation, see Modular Arithmetic. Using some properties of modular arithmetic, we have
$$
10^n+100^n+1000^n-3 \equiv 1+1+1-3\equiv0(\bmod 9)
$$
Therefore, it is divisible for 9.
If you prefer not to use this notation, we can express in the following way. There exist integers $a,b$ and $c$ such that $10^n=9a+1$, $100^n=9b+1$, and $1000^n=9c+1$. Therefore:
$$
10^n+100^n+1000^n-3=9(a+b+c)+3-3=9(a+b+c).
$$
This shows that the expression is indeed divisible by 9.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Alternative solution:
As, $$10^n=999...9 +1 \ = 9k_n +1$$ Hence $10^n + 100^n +1000^n = 10^n + 10^{2n} + 10^{3n} = 9(k_n + k_{2n} + k_{3n}) + 3$. Which is enough to prove your result.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)
